# attachment input php wp mail

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing an order form on a WordPress website. The form is created in HTML, and I use PHP to process the data, generate the HTML email, and send it to an email using WP MAIL SMTP. The order process works correctly for my project, but I'm having difficulty adding a file input.

The input I'm trying to use is this `<input type="file" id="requerimentoFileId" name="anexoEmail" accept=".pdf, .jpg, .jpeg, .png">`. How do I go about sending the file as an attachment in PHP?

```
<?php

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/site/wp-load.php');

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // Coleta dados do formulário
    $nomeRequerente = $_POST["nomeRequerente"];
    $emailRequerente = $_POST["emailRequerente"];
    $telefoneRequerente = $_POST["telefoneRequerente"];
    $nomeRegistrado = $_POST["nomeRegistrado"];
    $nomePaiRegistrado = $_POST["nomePaiRegistrado"];
    $nomeMaeRegistrado = $_POST["nomeMaeRegistrado"];
    $dataNascRegistrado = $_POST["dataNascRegistrado"];
    $livroRegistrado = $_POST["livroRegistrado"];
    $folhaLivroRegistrado = $_POST["folhaLivroRegistrado"];
    $termoLivroRegistrado = $_POST["termoLivroRegistrado"];
    $tipoCertidao = $_POST["tipoCertidao"];
    $mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];
    $entregaOpcao = $_POST["entrega"];

    $destinatario = "email@exemple.com";
    $assunto = "Pedido de Certidão de Nascimento";

    // Template HTML
    $template = <<<EOD
    <h2 style="color: #4d71e6; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 1.5rem; font-style: normal; font-weight: 500; line-height: normal; margin: 22px 0 32px;">Pedido Certidão de Nascimento</h2>
EOD;

    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    // Enviar e-mail usando wp_mail
    if (wp_mail($destinatario, $assunto, $template, $headers)) {
        echo 'success';
    } else {
        echo 'error';
    }

} else {

    echo 'error';

}

?>
```

Comment: [wp_mail has an `attachments` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)